# Why I don't see my facebook friends in graph explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

When in **Facebook Graph Explorer** I executed `/me/friends` command from [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends/), I get next response:

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 68
  }
}
```

So, based on response, I have 68 friends (it's true), but data array is empty, and I don't see my friends in array.

What I do wrong? I think, maybe I need to config my application? but I don't know what exactly t config. Help, please

Comment: API v2.0 introduced a lot of changes – one of them, that you will only get friends of the current user that are also using the same app. Go read their changelog please.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! But can I get a list of friends, which are not only using the same app, if I will be used a `v1.0` version? Or maybe there are some other solution for it?

Comment: Yes, you can with v1.0 (if your app was created before April 30th 2014). But v1.0 will become inactive on April 30th 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new Graph API (v2.0), your application must ask for the `user_friends` permission in order to retrieve friends. Additionally, this new permission now only returns friends who also use the same application.

If you want to get the complete friends list for tagging / invite purposes, there are two new APIs you can use: `/me/taggable_friends` or `/me/invitable_friends` - the latter is only available to Games.

[See this tutorial for more information](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/06/12/facebook-api-getting-friends-using-graph-api-2-0-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/).